# Is 3 dot menu(Option menu overflow) in action bar an image or a default icon provided by android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow

does 3 dotted menu appear automatically in action bar or do i need to add image manually?

[3dotImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwTR0.png)

Comment: It appears automatically for android version > 3.0. For lower versions you have to do programmatically using `ActionBarSherlock`.

Comment: @AbhishekV is correct. Also AbhishekV, If you want your answer to be accepted you'll need to submit an "Answer" rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears automatically for android version > 3.0. For lower versions you have to do programmatically using `ActionBarSherlock`

Comment: so i need not to mention android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" on top item

Comment: No.It is not the preferred method.what is `android:minSdkVersion` for your app?

Comment: Android Jelly Bean 4.1

Comment: May be some problem with the emulator.Try running it in real device.

Comment: NOTE: 2 caveats. 1. If the device has a physical "settings" button, the 3 dots will NEVER appear. 2. When adding the items if you don't specify it to only show in the overflow or no items need to be in the overflow then the 3 dots also won't show.

Answer (score 0):

If your menu items has action as ifRoom or if there is no enough space for menu items, They will go into overflow menu which looks like 3 dotted. You don't need to add image to it

Comment: Are you using real device or emulator?

Comment: even you keep action as ifRoom but there is enough space for those items, they will not go into overflow menu

Comment: i have only  two item 
<item>
<menu>

<item />
<item/>

</menu>
</item>

Comment: there may be enough space for menu items. are they appearing in ActionBar?

Comment: without adding 3 dotted icon its not displaying

plz check the following images

http://i.imgur.com/ovH3Wwp.jpg 
http://i.imgur.com/mKmMcYx.jpg

Comment: @Gopal Rao do i need any changes to be made in the code which is shown in the above posted image links

Comment: as You have only two menu items and they have enough space in ActionBar and as there are no overflow menu items, 3 dotted image will not be there anymore by default.and it is highly discouraged to add custom drawable as 3 dotted menu image

Comment: please let me know how would i create 3 dotted menu in detail

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the image manually  in drawable download the images from the below link

[Download](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html)

Comment: As @AbhishekV and Randy said its not showing automatically though i am developing for android version 4.1 Jelly Bean